# Application files path in android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm working on an android application, I need to get the path where the files generated by the app are stored, conosco that using this:

```
this.getFilesDir();
```

or I can get that folder through:

```
OutputStreamWriter fout=
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        openFileOutput("prueba_int.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

fout.write("Texto de prueba.");
fout.close();
```

and then:

```
getFileStreamPath("samplefile.txt");
```

I can get that route, but I am making a library and I need to place a series of files in the specified path without using parameters or the context of the activity.

there is way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is way to get it?

No.

You will need to modify your library to accept something as input that will let you read and write your data where and how the app wants. Ideally, you use some sort of Java interface that allows the app some flexibility (e.g., stores your data in its own encrypted container), with you supplying a stock implementation that perhaps uses `File` from the app's own `Context`.

Comment: excelent that was my plan b, but i want to make sure there is no other way to do it, you could indicate me where i can get info about that encrypted container.thanks for the help and show me another way to do the same think i want to do

Comment: @OtaconRex: "where i can get info about that encrypted container" -- well, the app could do anything from using `javax.crypto` directly themselves to using something [like `IOCipher`](https://guardianproject.info/code/iocipher/).